# Sounds play with delay

Tags: c#

here is my code:

```
        MediaPlayer player = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();

       bool playing = false;

        bool _bKeyIsDown = false;

        protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_bKeyIsDown) return;
            _bKeyIsDown = true;
            // play sound;
            base.OnKeyDown(e);
        } 
        protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e) 
        { 
            base.OnKeyUp(e);
            _bKeyIsDown = false;
        }

        private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D1)
            {
                if (label5.Text == "Waiting 01.wav")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No beat loaded");
                    return;
                }
                    pictureBox6.Image = Form1.Properties.Resources.white_square_button;
                    try
                    {
                        playing = true;
                        player.Open(new Uri(label37.Text));
                        player.Volume = (double)trackBar4.Value / 100;
                        player.Play();
                    }
                    catch (FileNotFoundException)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("File has been moved." + "\n" + "Please relocate it now!");
                    }
            }
}

        private void Window_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D1)
            {
                pictureBox6.Image = Form1.Properties.Resources.black_square_button;
                player1.Stop();
                player1.Close();
                playing = false;
            }
```

This what makes is to play a sound while key is down, but the problem is that when you release that key and press another one the sound delays and if you press 2 keys at the same time it only play the first one you pressed.

If you remove if `(_bKeyIsDown) return;` it does the trick but the sound won't play at its full length.

Is there a way to fix this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Which sound won't play at it's full length; the one already playing or the new one?

Comment: Both of them, it will won't play all the sounds at its full length.

Comment: It looks like to me that you're stopping the sound on key up.

Comment: if you want to play 2 sounds at the same time then you should initiate a new instance of wmp you have 1 instance called player so it would override the sound being played, also when you call the key up you have the wrong player instance to stop what was playing, you're calling player2 and you should not need the override at all for what u need since you have the `playing` just use that to check what u need

Answer (score 0):

If its just play and stop 1 sound just do KeyDown event and use bool to toggle:

```
        bool playing = false;
        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D1)
            {
                if (!playing)
                {

                    player.Open(new Uri(yourURI));
                    player.Play();
                    playing = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    player.Stop();
                    playing = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

EDIT:

then may i suggest you create a dictionary with all the sounds you need like this:

```
        Dictionary<Keys, Uri> sounds = new Dictionary<Keys, Uri>()
        {
            {Keys.A,new Uri(@"C:\..\..\youraudiofile.mp3")},
            {Keys.B,new Uri(@"C:\..\yourotheraudiofile.wma")}
        };
```

and create a list to keep references to the mediaplayers:

```
List<MediaPlayer> myplayers = new List<MediaPlayer>();
```

then only in KeyDown event(remove the onKeyDown,and keyup also):

```
        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
               foreach (MediaPlayer m in myplayers)
               {
                  m.Stop();
               }
               return;
            }

            if (sounds.ContainsKey(e.KeyCode))
            {
                MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
                mp.Open(sounds[e.KeyCode]);
                mp.Play();
            }
        }
```

Comment: its the same... the problem is this:         protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (bKeyIsDown) bKeyIsDown = false;
            bKeyIsDown = true;
            // play sound;
            base.OnKeyDown(e);
        }
        protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnKeyUp(e);
            bKeyIsDown = false;
        }

Comment: what effectively do you need to do?press key and play sound then press other key and play other sound above the first,or stop the first and play the second?(i mean press key and realese it to play sound)

Comment: Press key and play sound then press key and play other sound above first.